# How to not override value of the field when setting minDate in jquery ui datepicker?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to configure a `minDate` of the `#start_date's` datepicker, without overriding the input value itself. For example `#start_date` already has value of `01.06.2018` and I want to set up `minDate` when someone selects the field to be 
 equal or higher than today. The problem is that when I use code below the input in the field automatically changes to today. I want the field to be unchanged until I select a new date with the datepicker that is constricted to be equal or higher than today.

```
$("#start_date").datepicker("option",{
  minDate: new Date()
});
```

I also tried:

```
$("#start_date").datepicker({ minDate: 0});
```

And also destroy and recreate datepicker.

I come up with that solution, but I would prefer not to use this, because it is not elegant:

```
var start_date = self.$('#start_date').val();
$("#start_date").datepicker("option",{
  minDate: new Date()
});
self.$('#start_date').val(start_date);
```

I am using jQuery-ui-1.10.3.

Comment: I think your solution is the only real way to do this. jQuery is automatically validating the current value when you set `minDate` and removing it as it's no longer valid for the rules provided.

Comment: Set your current date value in input box and in datepicker simply add { minDate: 0}

Comment: @DsRaj what you described is I believe my solution

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks, that is what I was suspecting, I hoped to be otherwise

Comment: Something does not seem right here. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: do mark the answer as correct if it helped you out

Answer (score 0):

If I get you correctly you don't want the date in the input field to be changed on opening the datepicker unless you click on any of the dates.

If that is correct, there is one way to bind the datepicker to an element other than input like a `span` or `div` and then make it hidden initially and open manually by binding the `click` event to the input or even an icon to open the datepicker using `$(element).toggle()` and the important thing is that you have to assign the value to the input field manually using the `onSelect` event of the datepicker in this case.

See a demo below i created you can even click on the icon or the input field to open the date picker but it won't change the date inside the input field until you click on any of the dates. by default, I have added an older date to the input field so that you can click on it and see it remains same until you change

```js
$("#span-trigger").datepicker({
  minDate: new Date(),
  onSelect: function(date) {
    $("#date-field").val(date);
  }
}).hide();

$(".fa-calendar,#date-field").on("click", function() {
  $("#span-trigger").toggle();
});
```

```css
#span-trigger {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>

  <i class="fas fa-calendar"></i>
  <input type="text" id="date-field" value="06/01/2018">
  <span id="span-trigger"></span>
</p>
```